# SQL Cheatsheet?

Tags: sql

Just wondering if anyone has any favourite SQL references they to use when creating new queries. Possibly something that shows syntax, or available functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for one with just very basic functions you can try this to see if it fits your need.

http://www.sql.su/

You might have to paste the parts that you want into a better printing format as the top of the page has google ads =(

Comment: You ROCK bobo!! Good advice FTW!!

Answer (score 4):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/02/sql-server-2008-cheat-sheet-one-page-pdf-download/

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of the [O'Reilly SQL pocket guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013471.do).  It covers most of the major DB system types, and explains some of the functions that are unique to certain ones.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a handy little reference sheet for *basic* syntax and functions/statements: [SQL Cheat Sheet](http://www.zentut.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/sqlcheatsheet.jpg)

Comment: looks good. this image must extend to have more commands.

Answer (score 0):

Also O'Reilly SQL pocket guide for a quick glance. Covers Oracle, DB2, SQL Server and MySQL. For more detailed questions, Date/Darwen: A Guide to the SQL Standard, MySQL Reference Manual ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ ). or just Google.